# Domain keeps getting rewritten without mod_rewrite enabled

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, mod-rewrite

So essentially when I go to `http://www.example.com` OR `http://example.com` the URL gets rewritten to just `www.example.com` OR `example.com` **dropping/removing** the `http://` part. I'm not sure why this is happening really.

My DNS settings are the following on DigitalOcean:

[image: DNS Setting]

My virtualhost file is the following:

`<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin admin@example.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www.example.com/public_html
     ServerName www.example.com
     ServerAlias example.com
     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>`

It's not a big deal, but I'd really like to know why `http://` is being dropped from the URL and I'd also like to keep it from being dropped. I'm 100% sure `mod_rewrite` is not enabled. Running  VPS on DigitalOcean with `Ubuntu Server 14.04 x32` if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking at the URL that you type at the browser's address-bar. If that is so, this behavior is just a "*cosmetic effect*" and it varies from browser to browser. In google-chrome browser the protocol (`http://`) gets removed but in firefox the protocol is displayed.

But when a request is made to the webserver the browser follows the standard `GET / HTTP/1.1` HTTP header and so there should be no problem.

If there is any URL rewrite with protocol cut off then you have to get a URL redirection response code 301 or 302. To verify that try using `curl` command. Here `http://google.com` gets redirected to `http://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=9dvBVIbsIqXV8geunYHgDg`

```
$ curl -IL http://google.com
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Location: http://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=9dvBVIbsIqXV8geunYHgDg
Content-Length: 261
Connection: keep-alive

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 23 Jan 2015 05:28:21 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Accept-Ranges: none
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Connection: keep-alive
```

Comment: Haha this is entirely correct! I wasn't aware that this is just a behavior Chrome takes. I don't have FF installed, I have Opera but that's Chromium based now. So I just tested on IE and it worked! The `http://` was kept and not removed. Thank you for the explaination!